# Evaluate the surface integral over a torus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals, orientation

Let $F(x) = \frac{x}{||x^3||}$ and let $B$ be the 3D region formed when the circle $(z - 2)^2+y^2 = 1$, in the yz plane, is rotated about the y-axis. Evaluate $\int_{dB}F \cdot dS$.

This shape $dB$ should be a torus, with its 2D projection on the yz plane as a circle centered at (0,0,2) and a radius of 1. But I am not sure about my parametrization of the torus(I parametrized the inner "empty region" and the outermost circular region and then found their difference):
$\Phi_1(u,v) = (\cos v, u, \sin v)$ is the inner circle and $\Phi_2(u,v) = (3\cos v, u, 3\sin v)$ and I used $\Phi_2 - \Phi_1$ as my parametrization. Can someone check this for me or give a hint?

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry for a correct parametrization.

Comment: What can I do if I want to have the torus to be centered around the x or z axis?

Comment: The torus parametrized in Wikipedia is centered around, i.e. is rotation-invariant relative to, Z axis. If you want to center it around Z swap 'x' and 'z' in the equations.

Comment: Note that $\|x^3\|$ makes no sense. Do you have any specific knowledge about the force field $F$?

Comment: No I am not provided with any background information of the $||x^3||$